# sprintf hex number deleted

Tags: printf, zero

I am trying to get and send my MCU's IP Adress, SubnetMask and Gateway adress.
I got them but problem is merging them. I want to merge them with array and send for one step..

For example:

my values are
e2promIpAddress = 0A020705  // represents 10.2.7.5

e2promSubnetMask = FFFF0000  // represents 255.255.0.0

e2promGateway = 0A02070F  // represents 10.2.7.15

When I add with sprintf()

```
char buffer[64];
sprintf(buffer,"%x%x%x",e2promIpAddress,e2promSubnetMask,e2promGateway);
```

Output is A020705FFFF00000A02070F

Unfortunatelly array must start with 0 but it goes away..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally find my answer and want to post here..

My values for example e2promIpAddress = 0A020705 is 4 bytes.

When I wrote this with;

```
sprintf(buffer,"%02x%02x%02x",e2promIpAddress,e2promSubnetMask,e2promGateway);
```

it did not pad "0"

when I wrote this with;

```
sprintf(buffer,"%08x%08x%08x",e2promIpAddress,e2promSubnetMask,e2promGateway);
```

all values which starts with "0" pad with "0"

Have a good day..